# view contain all data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i'm learning Rails 3, i'm generating a User, a User have many Post. but when i'm creating some Post all data from database appear like this in user/view/show.html.erb :

> Post id: 2, title: "hello post", description: "hello posting", user_id: 2, created_at:"2013-03-01 16:18:07", updated_at: "2013-03-01 16:18:07"

my code in show.html.erb like this :
`<%= @user.posts.each do |post| %>
        <p>
        <%= post.title %>
        </p>
        <p>
        <%= post.description%>
        </p>
        <% end %>`

how to hide all post data from database? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `<%= %>` embed rather than `<% %>` for your loop (`<%= @user.posts.each do |post| %>`). The loop returns the array of Post objects, and then your use of `<%=` tells erb to stick that value into the page.

You want to use `<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>` instead (without `=`). That means to execute the code, but not display it's result.